# Enable link after hover state on touch devices without affecting normal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, touch

I have a `figure` element, which has a hover state on it which effects other elements within the figure; `img`, `figcaption` etc. I've been able to get this effect to "work" on touch devices, by using the following jQuery:

```
$('.portfolio__img').on("touchEnd", function (e) {
    "use strict"; //satisfy the code inspectors
    var link = $(this); //preselect the link
    if ( $( link ).hasClass( "portfolio__img--taphover" ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        link.addClass("portfolio__img--taphover");
        $('.portfolio__img').not(this).removeClass("portfolio__img--taphover");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent return points
    }
})

// portfolio__img--taphover` has the same CSS rules as `figure:hover, figure:focus`
```

I've forgotten where I got the code from now, but it was a blog post. This works quite well, however I'm not completely satisfied with it. If you touch and scroll, so scrolling quite a long way down the page, you are likely to miss the hover effect, as the element may not be within the viewport on `touchEnd`. However, my figure element is 100% width, so using `touchStart` impacts scrolling, as the instant a user touches the screen the hover effect is applied. I've looked around and there doesn't seem to be a touchTap or similar event. I suppose this is because its extremely difficult to work out if a user is touching (tapping) the screen to reveal something, or touching to swipe and scroll. I tried `touchMove` but that didn't work well.

I was convinced there would be a way to do it with CSS, for example making my overlay link have a low `z-index` which only gets higher on hover. Perhaps I could delay the `z-index` change until after the tap event, but then I still get into the whole issue of detecting a tap vs touch/scroll. Has anyone else encountered this behaviour and been annoyed by it, and/or found a solution?

My HTML:

```
<figure class="grid__item  mobile--one-half  desk--one-quarter  portfolio__img">

    <img class="portfolio__test" srcset="<?php echo $image_src; ?> 1536w, 
        <?php echo $image_src_1024; ?> 1024w, 
        <?php echo $image_src_900; ?> 900w, 
        <?php echo $image_src_600; ?> 600w,
        <?php echo $image_src_320; ?> 320w"
    sizes="(min-width: 78.75em) 25vw, (min-width: 30em) 50vw, 100vw" 
    alt="<?php the_field( 'portfolio_alt_text' ); ?>">
    <figcaption>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <h2><?php the_sub_field( 'portfolio_description' ); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </figcaption>
    <a class="portfolio__link" href="<?php the_sub_field( 'portfolio_link' ); ?>">View More</a>

</figure>
```

Relevent CSS:

```
.portfolio__link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Cheers. I'll update this question in due course once I find a good solution, in case no one has one!

**EDIT: Updated with Codepen example**

So I realise I wasn't that clear before so I've made a couple of codepen's that illustrate the issue I'm having:

Without a proper link ( `href="#"` ) http://codepen.io/patrickwc/pen/yyYVeV

If you touch these links with a touch device, the hover effect works and its very nice. You can still swipe and scroll without triggering the hover effect and when you touch another box after touching a previous box, the effect stops on the previous box and applies to the current box very nicely. I am seeking this behaviour. @Edgar Sanchez you mentioned permorance, its not jank or anything its the fact that with `touchstart` as soon as you touch the box, the effect triggers. What I want is an effect like the hover effect, which still allows you to swipe and scroll past without triggering the hover state (or --taphover class).

With a proper link (No js) http://codepen.io/patrickwc/pen/jEbVWq

Obviously now the boxes don't work very well. The browser tries to take you to http://www.something.com/ immediately, without respecting the hover state.

Ideally I want some javascript that enables the `jac-rollover__link` only after the hover state. I guess that could work actually, maybe jquery's hover state could then enable the class to make the z-index of it higher... I'll give it a go now.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the end result you want to achieve. You mentioned trying `touchstart` and that it impacted the scrolling performance? There is some optimizations that can be made to the code above that might help. Performance aside, if you applied the class "portfolio__img--taphover" on `touchstart` and removed the class on `touchend`, would that essentially be the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Edgar, thanks for replying and sorry for the delay. I've made some codepen's and edited the original question to illustrate the behaviour I'd like. I'd love to hear what optimisations could help the js code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working via pure CSS. I put `visibility: hidden` on the `jac-rollover__link`, then I used a CSS transition on visibility, with a length of 0s but with a delay of 0.5s, which is the same time the hover effect takes to complete. So, viola no javascript and it works really well on everything I've tested on so far. I suppose pretty much all touch devices with have support for CSS transitions, so it should be fine.

code in case it helps others:

```
.jac-rollover {
    ...

    &:hover,
    &:focus {

        .jac-rollover__link {
            visibility: visible;
            transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
        }
    }
}

.jac-rollover__link {
    ...
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I suppose the only drawback is if you are using a normal mouse, you have to wait 0.5s before the link works. But meh, I like this far better than the touchstart method.